# How to complete the missing values of the long form data frame based on reference vectors

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following data frame:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)


df <- tibble(
  source = c("a", "b", "b"),
  day = c("D1", "D2", "D3"),
  score = c(10, 5, 3) ) 


df
```

Which looks like this:

```
> df
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  source day   score
  <chr>  <chr> <dbl>
1 a      D1       10
2 b      D2        5
3 b      D3        3
```

Now the values for `source` and `day` are incomplete. The full list of `source` and `day` is
stored as vectors:

```
complete_source <- c("a", "b","c")
complete_day <- c("D1", "D2" ,"D3", "D4")
```

What I want to do is to complete the data frame based on `complete_source` and `complete_day`, 
filling the value with zero (0).

The desired result is (hand made):

```
 source day   score
 a      D1       10
 a      D2        0
 a      D3        0
 a      D4        0
 b      D2        5
 b      D3        3
 ... etc ...
 c      D1        0
 c      D2        0
 c      D3        0
 c      D4        0
 ...etc
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `complete`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
complete(df, source = complete_source, day = complete_day, fill = list(score = 0))
# A tibble: 12 x 3
#   source day   score
#   <chr>  <chr> <dbl>
# 1 a      D1       10
# 2 a      D2        0
# 3 a      D3        0
# 4 a      D4        0
# 5 b      D1        0
# 6 b      D2        5
# 7 b      D3        3
# 8 b      D4        0
# 9 c      D1        0
#10 c      D2        0
#11 c      D3        0
#12 c      D4        0
```

---

Or do a `crossing` with the `vector`s and join

```
crossing(source = complete_source, day = complete_day) %>% 
        left_join(df) %>%
        mutate(score = replace_na(score, 0))
```

---

In `base R`, this can be done with `expand.grid/merge`

```
transform(merge(expand.grid(source = complete_source, 
      day = complete_day), df, all.x = TRUE), 
      score = replace(score, is.na(score), 0))
```